# How to click QTreeWidgetItem programmatically

Tags: python, pyqt

There is a function that is triggered when QTreeWidgetItem is clicked by the user.
I wonder if there is a way to "click" an item programmatically. I've tried

```
.setCurrentIndex(index)
.setCurrentItem(item)
```

but while these methods set the item "active" they do not trigger onClick function.

Comment: Please provide some more information about onClick function, where does it live in your code and how is it triggered in normal situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- connect the signal `treeWidget.currentItemChanged` to onClick
- Get the current item and save it in a variable
- Change the current item using `setCurrentItem(item)` method

```
treeWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(onClick)
previousItem = treeWidget.currentItem()
treeWidget.setCurrentItem(item)

def onClick(current, previous):
    print current.text(0) if current is not None else None # put the whatever index your item has
    print previous.text(0) if previous is not None else None
```

Comment: I wonder what this answer means in regard to the question. Is `setCurrentItem` indeed equivalent to a click on the item unlike the questioner stated?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the line just under the OP's posted code. I try to get more information from the OP. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

here is some code snippets to simulate mouse click on item of QTreeWidget. I hope it can help you.

```
# get the QTreeWidget object
treeWidget = self.form.treeWidget
# obtain the 0th child item of the 0th top level item
child = treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).child(0)
# obtain the rectangular coordinates of the child item
rect = treeWidget.visualItemRect(child)
# simulate the mouse click within the rectangular coordinates
QTest.mouseClick(treeWidget.viewport(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier,rect.center())
```